# How to remove unsafe inline and unsafe eval from content security policy?

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy

Can anyone know how to remove unsafe inline and unsafe eval from content security policy using nonce,
anyone have any resource how to implement nonce as i am unable to implement it properly i think i am getting errors in node.js application.
I have tried the helmet, meta tags, set Headers nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove 'unsafe-eval' with nonces, you'll need to rewrite or replace the code.

Nonces are hard. You will need to insert the nonce in the CSP and in code dynamically. It also needs to change with every pageload to be secure. Frameworks don't always permit this. Also remember that inline event handlers aren't nonceable and need to be rewritten. I would suggest to try to rewrite all static script and style into separate files and then see if you still need nonces for the rest or if you can handle it in other ways.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will try that

Comment: What about unsafe inline,

Comment: It depends a bit on the type of offending code:
Event attributes: move to a js or css file.
Static code or style: move to a js or css file.
Dynamic code or style: compute hash (or use nonce if you can).
Code or style inserted from third party packages: replace, rewrite, give up, or check if trusted types can help you.

Comment: Can i get any example or Source to implement Content-Security-Policy example? to implement nonce in the place of unsafe-inline?

Comment: It would be highly dependent on the framework you use. Unfortunately I don't have many examples as I have many times given up on nonces as the framework didn't support setting them or values were cached preventing updates with every pageload.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce is an apache module that can be used to implement nonce in place of unsafe-inline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33409344)